# Saving changed positions in SQL Server table X, Y columns

Tags: qgis, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table with X,Y columns linked to QGIS 3.6, and I made a virtual layer of it using "MakePoint(X,Y,CRS_id) as geometry".

Now I want to shift a point in the map and have the change stored in the X,Y columns of the SQL Server table. 
What I see is that I can not edit the virtual layer, so I can not shift its points. So, how to shift the points then? And if shifting points is possible, how to store the X,Y in the SQL Server table?
Our SQL Server version does not support spatial, still version 2005 (!).

Comment: It's unlikely you will find others using the combination of a recent QGIS and a fourteen year old database. In fact, it's amazing you can  get any functionality out of such a combination at all. Given all the vulnerabilities of using ancient software, it's probably time to modernize.

Comment: You are completely right! Updates are coming but due to dependencies between applications and that database it's not a matter of seconds to upgrade. So, any answer? Thanks!